# How do i stop detecting an object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, text-to-speech, coreml

I'm currently working IOS mobile project where objects are detected in a frame and then translated to speech to aid the visually impaired.  My application already detects objects in a frame, but once it does so it doesn't stop detecting. When I'm trying to convert the object name to speech it keeps iterating over the same name over and over again.

For clarification, when I point my camera at a "chair" it gives over a 100 log for chairs in which the text to speech has to say those 100 "chairs" before moving on to the next object.

This is my `viewController` code:

```
import UIKit
import Vision
import CoreMedia
import AVFoundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoPreview: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var boxesView: DrawingBoundingBoxView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelsTableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var inferenceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var etimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fpsLabel: UILabel!
    
    let objectDectectionModel = MobileNetV2_SSDLite()
    

    
    // MARK: - Vision Properties
    var request: VNCoreMLRequest?
    var visionModel: VNCoreMLModel?
    var isInferencing = false
    
    // MARK: - AV Property
    var videoCapture: VideoCapture!
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    var lastExecution = Date()
    
    // MARK: - TableView Data
    var predictions: [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] = []
    
    // MARK - Performance Measurement Property
    private let measure = Measure()
    
    let maf1 = MovingAverageFilter()
    let maf2 = MovingAverageFilter()
    let maf3 = MovingAverageFilter()
    
    // MARK: - View Controller Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // setup the model
        setUpModel()
        
        // setup camera
        setUpCamera()
        
        // setup delegate for performance measurement
        measure.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.videoCapture.start()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.videoCapture.stop()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup Core ML
    func setUpModel() {
        if let visionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: objectDectectionModel.model) {
            self.visionModel = visionModel
            request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel, completionHandler: visionRequestDidComplete)
            request?.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFill
        } else {
            fatalError("fail to create vision model")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - SetUp Video
    func setUpCamera() {
        videoCapture = VideoCapture()
        videoCapture.delegate = self
        videoCapture.fps = 30
        videoCapture.setUp(sessionPreset: .vga640x480) { success in
            
            if success {
                // add preview view on the layer
                if let previewLayer = self.videoCapture.previewLayer {
                    self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    self.resizePreviewLayer()
                }
                
                // start video preview when setup is done
                self.videoCapture.start()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        resizePreviewLayer()
    }
    
    func resizePreviewLayer() {
        videoCapture.previewLayer?.frame = videoPreview.bounds
    }
}

// MARK: - VideoCaptureDelegate
extension ViewController: VideoCaptureDelegate {
    func videoCapture(_ capture: VideoCapture, didCaptureVideoFrame pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?, timestamp: CMTime) {
        // the captured image from camera is contained on pixelBuffer
        if !self.isInferencing, let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer {
            self.isInferencing = true
            
            // start of measure
            self.measure.start()
            
            // predict!
            self.predictUsingVision(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func predictUsingVision(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        guard let request = request else { fatalError() }
        // vision framework configures the input size of image following our model's input configuration automatically
        self.semaphore.wait()
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        try? handler.perform([request])
    }
    
    // MARK: - Post-processing
    func visionRequestDidComplete(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        self.measure.labell(with: "endInference")
        if let predictions = request.results as? [VNRecognizedObjectObservation] {
//            print(predictions.first?.labels.first?.identifier ?? "nil")
//            print(predictions.first?.labels.first?.confidence ?? -1)
            
            let pred = request.results?.first
//            print(pred)
//            print(predictions.first?.labels.first?.identifier as Any)
            
//            print(predictions)
 
            
            self.predictions = predictions
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.boxesView.predictedObjects = predictions
                self.labelsTableView.reloadData()

                // end of measure
                self.measure.end()
                
                self.isInferencing = false
            }
        } else {
            // end of measure
            self.measure.end()
            
            self.isInferencing = false
        }
        self.semaphore.signal()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return predictions.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoCell") else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        // Getting the detected object and translating them to speech.
        // This is where i face the problem of translating the objects as the objects
        // keep iterating over themsleves.
        
        let result = predictions[indexPath.row].label ?? "N/A"
        
    

// when trying to print(result) i get all the labells detected but it does not stop.

        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: result)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
        utterance.rate = 0.5

        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)

        let rectString = predictions[indexPath.row].boundingBox.toString(digit: 2)
        let confidence = predictions[indexPath.row].labels.first?.confidence ?? -1
        let confidenceString = String(format: "%.3f", confidence/*Math.sigmoid(confidence)*/)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = predictions[indexPath.row].label ?? "N/A"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(rectString), \(confidenceString)"
        
        
        return cell
        
        
        

        
    }
}

// MARK: - (Performance Measurement) Delegate
extension ViewController: MeasureDelegate {
    func updateMeasure(inferenceTime: Double, executionTime: Double, fps: Int) {
        //print(executionTime, fps)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.maf1.append(element: Int(inferenceTime*1000.0))
            self.maf2.append(element: Int(executionTime*1000.0))
            self.maf3.append(element: fps)
            
            self.inferenceLabel.text = "inference: \(self.maf1.averageValue) ms"
            self.etimeLabel.text = "execution: \(self.maf2.averageValue) ms"
            self.fpsLabel.text = "fps: \(self.maf3.averageValue)"
        }
    }
}

class MovingAverageFilter {
    private var arr: [Int] = []
    private let maxCount = 10
    
    public func append(element: Int) {
        arr.append(element)
        if arr.count > maxCount {
            arr.removeFirst()
        }
    }
    
    public var averageValue: Int {
        guard !arr.isEmpty else { return 0 }
        let sum = arr.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        return Int(Double(sum) / Double(arr.count))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you call `tableView.reloadData()` in every frame, because `visionRequestDidComplete` is called each frame. Thus, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (and therein `AVSpeechSynthesizer` ) gets called over and over which produces the sound.

You should re-evaluate if you need to update your tableview that often. Maybe you only need to update the tableview, if there are new observations? You could check for that using the `predictions` array in `visionRequestDidComplete`.

You might also wanna use Apple's own VoiceOver system to read out UI elements. That's the standard approach to add support for visually impaired users. This would also offer the benefit that the user can navigate within the tableview and the text of each cell will be read out accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, yeah I've been trying to do so but it seems i just can't get it right, would you be able in assisting with that? Any guide on how to do it would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a large topic and can't be explained in a few sentences. 
Here is Apple's [documentation of Voice Over](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility_for_ios_and_tvos/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app), if you wanna read up about it.